# Prioritizing a specific url in start_urls (Scrapy)

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a very long list of `start_urls` that has been working great previously. However, now I need to go to a single specific `start_url` first, and then do the rest of the `start_urls` afterwards. I tried placing the url I need to go to first at the front of `start_urls`, however it is no gurantee that scrapy will parse that url first, which is what I need.

`http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=CAT` is the url that needs to be scraped first, before all other start_urls, as seen at the front below:

```
    start_urls = [
    'http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=CAT', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/B.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/C.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/D.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/E.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/F.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/G.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/H.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/I.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/J.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/K.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/L.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/M.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/N.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/O.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/P.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/Q.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/R.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/S.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/T.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/U.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/V.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/W.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/X.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/Y.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/TSX/Z.htm'
    'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/B.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/C.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/D.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/E.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/F.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/G.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/H.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/I.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/J.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/K.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/L.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/M.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/N.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/O.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/P.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/Q.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/R.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/S.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/T.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/U.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/V.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/W.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/X.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/Y.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/Z.htm',
    'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/B.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/C.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/D.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/E.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/F.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/G.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/H.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/I.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/J.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/K.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/L.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/M.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/N.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/O.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/P.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/Q.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/R.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/S.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/T.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/U.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/V.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/W.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/X.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/Y.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/Z.htm',
    'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/HKEX/0.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/HKEX/1.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/HKEX/2.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/HKEX/3.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/HKEX/6.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/HKEX/8.htm',
    'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/0.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/1.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/2.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/3.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/4.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/5.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/6.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/7.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/8.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/9.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/A.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/B.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/C.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/D.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/E.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/F.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/G.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/H.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/I.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/G.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/K.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/L.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/M.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/N.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/O.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/P.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/Q.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/R.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/S.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/T.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/U.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/V.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/W.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/X.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/Y.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/LSE/Z.htm',
    'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/A.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/B.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/C.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/D.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/E.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/F.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/G.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/H.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/I.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/J.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/K.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/L.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/M.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/N.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/O.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/P.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/Q.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/R.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/S.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/T.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/U.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/V.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/W.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/X.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/Y.htm', 'http://eoddata.com/stocklist/AMS/Z.htm',
    'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=A', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=B', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=C', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=D', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=E', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=F', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=G', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=H', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=I', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=J', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=K', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=L', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=M', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=N', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=O', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=P', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=Q', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=R', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=S', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=T', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=U', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=V', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=W', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=X', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=Y', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EIXIC&alpha=Z',
    'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EHSI&alpha=0', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EHSI&alpha=1', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EHSI&alpha=2', 'https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EHSI&alpha=3',
    'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=A', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=B', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=C', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=D', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=E', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=F', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=G', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=H', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=I', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=J', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=K', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=L', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=M', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=N', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=O', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=P', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=Q', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=R', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=S', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=T', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=U', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=V', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=W', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=X', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=Y', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EN100&alpha=Z',
    'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=A', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=B', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=C', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=D', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=E', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=F', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=G', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=H', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=I', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=J', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=K', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=L', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=M', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=N', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=O', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=P', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=Q', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=R', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=S', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=T', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=U', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=V', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=W', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=X', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=Y', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFCHI&alpha=Z',
    'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=A', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=B', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=C', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=D', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=E', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=F', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=G', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=H', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=I', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=J', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=K', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=L', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=M', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=N', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=O', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=P', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=Q', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=R', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=S', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=T', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=U', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=V', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=W', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=X', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=Y', 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EAEX&alpha=Z'
]
```

I was wondering if I could somehow prioritize `'http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=CAT'`, and then do the rest. I am guessing that this would involve leaving `'http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=CAT'` in the start_urls, and taking the rest out. Then, initiating those other urls somehow later in the program, but I'm not sure how to do this...

Thankful for any and all suggestions.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22043797/scrapy-doesnt-handle-requests-in-priority-order) help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566322/scrapy-crawl-urls-in-order/6593427 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16875580/the-order-of-scrapy-crawling-urls-with-long-start-urls-list-and-urls-yiels-from

Comment: You can try using frontera: http://frontera.readthedocs.org
Tutorial here: http://blog.scrapinghub.com/2015/04/22/frontera-the-brain-behind-the-crawls/